# Why can I catch a SyntaxError (or IndentationError or TabError) raised by eval'd code, but not caused by the source code itself?

Tags: python, exception

Consider these two snippets:

```
try:
    a+a=a
except SyntaxError:
    print "first exception caught"
```

.

```
try:
    eval("a+a=a")
except SyntaxError:
    print "second exception caught"
```

In the second case the "second exception .." statement is printed (exception caught), while in the first one isn't.

Is first exception (lets call it "SyntaxError1") any different from second one ("SyntaxError2")?

Is there any way to catch SyntaxError1 (thus supressing compilation-time errors)? Wrapping large blocks of code in `eval` is unsatisfactory ;)

Comment: Suppressing compile-time errors???? What can that possibly mean?  Can you provide some definition for the use case in which you want unparseable code to parse?  What is supposed to happen?  How bad can the code be and yet still be "parsed"?  What are you talking about?

Comment: Question was focused mainly on possible inconsistency of SyntaxErrors thrown in different situation. Alex explained that there's no inconsistency at all, and all the described behaviour consists in compiler's mechanisms of constructing higher-level structure of try/except. One probable use case might be uploading by a trusted developer *.py file with some functionality (simple plugin system?), with necessity of validating its syntax right after upload.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the first case, the exception is raised by the compiler, which is running *before* the `try/except` structure even *exists* (since it's the compiler itself that will set it up right after parsing).  In the second case, the compiler is running twice -- and the exception is getting raised when the compiler runs as part of `eval`, *after* the first run of the compiler has already set up the `try/except`.

So, to intercept syntax errors, one way or another, you have to arrange for the compiler to run twice -- `eval` is one way, explicit `compile` built-in function calls another, `import` is quite handy (after writing the code to another file), `exec` and `execfile` other possibilities yet.  But however you do it, syntax errors can be caught only after the compiler has run one first time to set up the `try/except` blocks you need!

Comment: I wasn't aware of variety of solutions. Especially one with explicit import solves my hidden case elegantly. Thanks a lot, Alex!

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: No.

Syntax errors happen when the code is parsed, which for normal Python code is before the code is executed - the code is not executing inside the try/except block since the code is not executing, period.

However when you eval or exec some code, then you are parsing it at runtime, so you can catch the exception.