# Catching Python runtime errors only

Tags: python

I find myself handling exceptions without specifying an exception type when I call code that  interacts with system libraries like shutil, http, etc, all of which can throw if the system is in an unexpected state (e.g. a file locked, network unavailable, etc)

```
try:
    # call something
except:
    print("OK, so it went wrong.")
```

This bothers me because it also catches `SyntaxError` and other exceptions based in programmer error, and I've seen recommendations to avoid such open-ended exception handlers.

Is there a convention that all runtime errors derive from some common exception base class that I can use here? Or anything that doesn't involve syntax errors, module import failures, etc.? Even `KeyError` I would consider a bug, because I tend to use dict.get() if I'm not 100% sure the key will be there.

I'd hate to have to list every single conceivable exception type, especially since I'm calling a lot of supporting code I have no control over.

**UPDATE:** OK, the answers made me realize I'm asking the wrong question -- what I'm really wondering is if there's a Python convention or explicit recommendation for library writers to use specific base classes for their exceptions, so as to separate them from the more mundane `SyntaxError` & friends.

Because if there's a convention for library writers, I, as a library consumer, can make general assumptions about what might be thrown, even if specific cases may vary. Not sure if that makes more sense?

**UPDATE AGAIN**: Sven's answer finally led me to understand that instead of giving up and catching everything at the top level, I can handle and refine exceptions at the lower levels, so the top level only needs to worry about the specific exception type from the level below.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I had searched but didn't manage to weed out a clear answer. Where is the divide between parsing/syntax/programmer errors and runtime errors?

Comment: Note that you can't usually catch a `SyntaxError` -- it will be thrown when *compiling* the source, long before it is executed.  The only cases a `SyntaxError` can be catched if your `try` block contains `import`, `exec`, `execfile()` or `eval()`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Huh, I was sure I'd seen these type-less handlers catch even syntax errors, but it could've been something else, more subtle. I don't have a clean example handy. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @KimGräsman: A `SyntaxError` means that some file can't even be *parsed*, so there is no way the code might start being *executed* -- see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856408/syntaxerror-inconsistency-in-python.

Comment: You can catch a `SyntaxError` on `exec` or `eval()` though, and I also think on `import` if there's a syntax error in the module you're importing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Always make the `try` block as small as possible.
2. Only catch the exceptions you want to handle.  Look in the documentation of the functions you are dealing with.

This ensures that you think about what exceptions may occur, and you think about what to do if they occur.  If something happens you never thought about, chances are your exception handling code won't be able to correctly deal with that case anyway, so it would be better the exception gets propagated.

You said you'd "hate to have to list every single conceivable exception type", but usually it's not that bad.  Opening a file?  Catch `IOError`.  Dealing with some library code?  They often have their own exception hierarchies with a specific top-level exception -- just catch this one if you want to catch any of the library-specific exceptions.  Be as specific as possible, otherwise errors will pass unnoticed sooner or later.

As for convention about user-defined exceptions in Python: They [usually should be derived from `Exception`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions).  This is also what most user-defined exceptions in the standard library derive from, so the least you should do is use

```
except Exception:
```

instead of a bare `except` clause, which also catches `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit`.  As you have noted yourself, this would still catch a lot of exceptions you don't want to catch.

Comment: Thanks for sage advice! I think `Exception` would get me into trouble with things like `OverflowError`, which I consider programmer error as well. But your note on library-specific exceptions got me thinking -- if I can wire all our internal modules to throw lib-specific exceptions, this will be much easier to handle. For the modules where I've already done this, error handling is much more straightforward.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this list of [built-in exceptions](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html) in the Python docs. It sounds like what you mostly want is to catch `StandardError` although this also includes `KeyError`. There are also other base classes, such as `ArithmeticError` and `EnvironmentError`, that you may find useful sometimes.

I find third-party libraries do derive their custom exceptions from `Exception` as documented here. Programmers also tend to raise standard Python exceptions such as `TypeError`, `ValueError`, etc. in appropriate situations. Unfortunately, this makes it difficult to consistently catch library errors separately from other errors derived from `Exception`. I wish Python defined e.g. a `UserException` base class. Some libraries do declare a base class for their exceptions, but you'd have to know what these are, import the module, and catch them explicitly.

Of course, if you want to catch everything *except* `KeyError` and, say, `IndexError`, along with the script-stopper exceptions, you could do this:

```
try:
    doitnow()
except (StopIteration, GeneratorExit, KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    raise    # these stop the script
except (KeyError, IndexError):
    raise    # we don't want to handle these ones
except Exception as e:
    handleError(e)
```

Admittedly, this becomes a hassle to write each time.

Comment: Nice, it didn't occur to me to explicitly catch and re-raise what I /don't/ want to catch.

Comment: "I wish Python defined e.g. a UserException base class." -- that's what I was hoping for, too. It seems atypical for Python, it's typically so strong with conventions.

Answer (score 1):

How about `RuntimeError`: http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.RuntimeError

If that isn't what you want (and it may well not be), look at the list of exceptions on that page. If you're confused by how the hierarchy fits together, I suggest you spend ten minutes examining the `__bases__` property of the exceptions you're interested in, to see what base classes they share. (Note that `__bases__` isn't closed over the whole hierarchy - you may need to examine superclass bases also).

Comment: "This exception is mostly a relic from a previous version of the interpreter; it is not used very much any more."

Comment: @kindall: The linked page has all of the built-in exceptions, so OP can pick what he likes, as you well know.

Comment: I was aware of RuntimeError, but I haven't found a clear recommendation for library writers to use it as a base for all runtime errors... Is there such a thing?

Comment: @Marcin; thanks, but I guess the fundamental problem is that I don't know what classes I'm interested in. Essentially I want to catch anything but programmer errors. See my update for more info, hope that helps clarify.