# Why isn't my code excepting the errors?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this little piece of code I wrote that isn't excepting the errors that could be thrown at it. Here's the code:

```
def println(stringint):
    try:
        print stringint
    except (SyntaxError, NameError):
        print "Invalid format."
```

I run the code from the python interpreter like this, and only like this:

```
>>> import pcl
>>> pcl.println("Hello")
```

Why aren't the errors being excepted? How can I catch the errors?

Comment: Seems nothing wrong with it. Why should it catch any error?

Comment: what behaviour do you want?

Comment: You do have an indentation (syntax) error in your code!

Comment: @AndrewJaffe Nah, that's just stackexchange's broken code formatting.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe Where's the SyntaxError though?

Comment: @SomeGuy no, it's not: I just fixed it.

Comment: @SomeGuy stackexchange's code formatting is not broken.

Comment: @SomeGuy: it looks like you've mixed tabs and spaces on the same line. That's... not a good idea.

Comment: @SomeGuy Bad indentation *is* a syntax error (in this case, I think).

Comment: People, don't edit example code. *Especially* not with a language like Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those errors that has to do with syntax are parse level errors, which means, that are errors that take place **before** that particular code being interpreted.

The following aren´t the same type of errors:

```
print("Hello)  # Note the missing '"'
```

that

```
print(4/0)     # Syntactically correct, but obviously an error.
```

Hence, syntax error can't be handled by the `try -- except` block.

See this answer for more detail: [SyntaxError inconsistency in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856408/syntaxerror-inconsistency-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, `"Hello"` should raise neither an `EOLError` nor a `NameError`, because the quotes are closed, and it is a string.

Comment: Well, I put NameError in the just in case the user enters something like `pcl.println(hello)`.

Comment: @SomeGuy Then NameError will be raised outside of your function call.

Comment: Function arguments are evaluated before the function is called. You can't catch `pcl.println(hello)` from *inside* `pcl.println()` because `pcl.println()` is never called (assuming there is no variable in scope named `hello`).

Comment: @SomeGuy What do you mean by "the user enters something like `pcl.println(hello)`"? The "user" is the person who is using the code. *You* are the person who is doing the programming, and doing the calls. If you are trying to use exceptions to help you catch errors in your program, that's not the right model.