# Why isn't Python excepting error in list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a simple list comprehension with "else 0" incorrectly placed at the end. I put that inside a `try` block, so I'm expecting the exception to be caught and the print statement to be executed. However, it's returning `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Here's the code:

```
try:
    [2 * x for x in [1,2,3] if x > 1 else 0]
except SyntaxError:
    print("Why isn't this printed?")
```

Why isn't the error being caught?

Comment: `[2 * x if x>1 else 0 for x in [1,2,3]]`?

Comment: Issue is with the syntax of your list comprehension.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon that seems to be the reason. Thanks for linking that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Syntax Error Inconsistency**

As `@BrianMcCutchon` mentions, if you are checking the [syntax error inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856408/syntaxerror-inconsistency-in-python), please use `eval` for the same-

```
try:
    eval("[2 * x for x in [1,2,3] if x > 1 else 0]") #<----
except SyntaxError:
    print("Why isn't this printed?")
```

```
Why isn't this printed?
```

---

**Syntax error in list comprehension**

The error gets fixed if you fix the `else` in your list comprehension.

```
try:
    [2 * x  if x > 1 else 0 for x in [1,2,3]] #<----
except SyntaxError:
    print("Why isn't this printed?")
```

As `@Ch3steR` mentions in their comment as well, please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension) for more details.

```
#Returning element based on condition
[i for i in l if condition=True]

#Adding if else in list comprehension
[i if condition=True else j for i in l]
```